# Prettier Github action failing for pull request to other people's repos

Tags: github, github-actions, prettier

I have been trying to set up [Prettier as a Github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/prettier-action) on my organization's repository. When run on pushes and pull requests to my own repository, the Prettier check succeeds, but when I submit a pull request to someone else's repository, it successfully prettifies the code, but the check fails with the following log:

```
Run creyD/prettier_action@v4.2
Run PATH=$(cd $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH; npm bin):$PATH /home/runner/work/_actions/creyD/prettier_action/v4.2/entrypoint.sh
Installing prettier...
Prettifying files...
Files:
about.html 50ms
contact.html 13ms
directoryscr.js 60ms
index.html 10ms
member.html 10ms
members/osenberg.json 6ms
members/rehwinkel.json 4ms
members/template.json 3ms
memberscr.js 25ms
membersdir.html 43ms
memberslist.json 5ms
README.md 88ms
No node_modules/ folder.
No package-lock.json file.
[detached HEAD ad83deb] Prettified Code!
 Author: iosenberg <iosenberg@users.noreply.github.com>
 5 files changed, 69 insertions(+), 74 deletions(-)
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>

Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

I have tried everything I can think of, and I can't seem to find much documentation for how to make this run. Any thoughts on what to try next? Here is my fork for reference: https://github.com/iosenberg/obiesource.github.io/tree/prettier